# Using android box 2d in my android project

Tags: android, box2d, jbox2d

I am trying to find the .jar file for android box 2d but haven't been successful.  So far I've found an apk supposedly with it but don't know how i'd use that.  Supposedly you can convert the apk to a jar, but is that what i'm looking for?

A secondary question is if there is a problem just using jbox2d instead of the android version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an SVN path you can check out. I had a look and it seems to contain an Android project with the .jar file you are looking for.

Checkout this path: http://androidbox2d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Answer (score 0):

Don't even bother with box2d, try [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/), which is specifically designed and optimized for Android, and contains not only box2d engine, but sound, sprites, openGL support and many-many game-related things you may use right from the box. did I mention samples? yes, there are aplenty!!

Comment: sounds pretty great, but for the project i'm working on we already agreed on box2d and that was hard enough

Comment: i'm pretty sure you'll regret not using `AndEngine` further down the road, when switching engines will be even harder. Have fun, though! =)

Comment: this answer does not address the question